# Jersey Client: Is it possible to intercept each request for performance measuring?

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am currently working on a Rest Client for a Rest Service we are currently developing. I want to be able to **measure the performance of all client calls**. One could easily do something like this:

```
WebTarget target ... // just assume a WebTarget is given
long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
Response response = target.request().get(); // execute the request
long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeTaken = after - before;
// now log timeTaken or whatever one might wanna do
```

**Is it possible to intercept each request, so that i can apply this code to each request?** I do not want to repeat this piece of code over and over again. I searched for a central piece of code that i could override to execute this code but i did not find something suitable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jersey 2.6 or higher you may be able to use the newly added [HK2 AOP feature](https://hk2.java.net/2.2.0/aop-example.html).  Basically what you would do is somewhere close to the initialization of your app you would add an implementation of [Interception Service](https://hk2.java.net/2.2.0/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/InterceptionService.html) and provide your AOP Alliance method interceptor.  You can then write whatever code you want to measure performance in your interceptors.

Comment: Thx. I will have a look into it. How do you register those Interceptors with Jersey Client? Are those Interceptor Services also Providers that can be registered on an instance of Client?

Comment: You might want to look here for Jersey client: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e4662.  I believe using the ServiceLocatorClientProvider class might be what you are looking for.